# "God is real" vs. "God exists"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Why do they say in English speaking world "God is real" to mean "God exists"?

Having watched multiple debates in English between believers in God and atheists, I came to realize that the phrase "God is real" in their debates means simply "God exists". It is exactly the phrase "God exists" that pops up in similar debates in my first language and it is the focal point that one side in such debates is trying to prove, and the other to disprove, in any language.

So, once again then: Why "God is real" and not "God exists"?

In my first language the phrase "God is real" implies, in fact, more than just the existence of God. It means that the existing God is well-manifested in this world, is doing His cause and can thus be observed by humans.

Is there any such difference in English between "God exists" and "God is real"?

Is it possible, in a native English speaker's mind, for God to be existing and yet to not be real?

Comment: No, there isn't a difference. "To exist" and "to be" are synonyms, so if something is real, it exists, and if something exists, it is real (unless otherwise stated, for example "his dream of owning his own store exists in his mind"). I'm not sure exactly what you mean by existing meaning something more, so I'm assuming there is a connotation in your first language that doesn't exist in English.

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon - "I'm not sure exactly what you mean by existing meaning something more" - It's not "existing" that in my first language means more, it's "being real" that means more.

Comment: As this native speaker of American English understands the proposition *God is real*, it is intended in contrast to a proposition such as *God is imaginary*. So it doesn’t carry a whole lot of connotational import that isn’t also conveyed by the proposition *God exists*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is in the *connotations* of the words.  **real** is an "everyday" or "ordinary" word whereas **exists** is a "bookish" word.  To say "God is real" emphasizes that God is (for those speakers) a presence in everyday life, not merely a subject of debate or a concept.